# same query, two different ways, vastly different performance

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbi

I have a Postgres table with more than 8 million rows. Given the following two ways of doing the same query via `DBD::Pg`, I get wildly different results.

```
$q .= '%';

## query 1
my $sql = qq{
    SELECT a, b, c
    FROM t 
    WHERE Lower( a ) LIKE '$q'
};
my $sth1 = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth1->execute();

## query 2
my $sth2 = $dbh->prepare(qq{
    SELECT a, b, c
    FROM t  
    WHERE Lower( a ) LIKE ?
});
$sth2->execute($q);
```

query 2 is at least an order of magnitude slower than query 1... seems like it is not using the indexes, while query 1 is using the index.

Would love hear why.

Comment: How are you measuring the speed?

Comment: initially it was simply from observing... the difference is so much that it is apparent. Then I put numbers to the observation with the help of `use Benchmark;`

Comment: You should try switching the order of the tests, to rule out any caching effects.

Comment: What's the value of `$q` before the first line?

Comment: yup, tried that already to eliminating caching. Trust me... there is a difference. Whether I do a standalone test or record the results in the actual application... there is an order of mag difference. No point in debating that. The question really is "why?"

Comment: @punkish: Your comment about how the value is bound may be instructive. Can you try the binding case but bind using an explicit TEXT type?, e.g. `$sth2->bind_param(1, $q, { pg_type => PG_TEXT }); $sth2->execute();` (You will need to `use DBD::Pg qw(:pg_types);` at the top to get `PG_TEXT`.)

Comment: @punkish: What index(es) do you have on table `t`? From the looks of it, you should have an index over `Lower(a)` (in contrast to just indexing over `a`).

Comment: I've asked another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276993/when-are-select-queries-planned) about when queries are planned

Comment: @punkish: Did you try binding $q with an explicit type? Only I would be interested to know if it makes a difference

Comment: What is the performance like if you don't append '%' to `$q` and use a where clause like `WHERE Lower( a ) LIKE ? || '%'`?

Comment: Cross posted at [perlmonks](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=953562)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `LIKE` expressions, b-tree indexes can only be used if the search pattern is left-anchored, i.e. **terminated with `%`**. [More details in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-types.html).
<sub>Thanks to @evil otto for the link. This link to the *current* version.</sub>

Your first query provides this essential information at prepare time, so the query planner can use a matching index.

Your second query does not provide any information about the pattern at prepare time, so the query planner cannot use any indexes.

Comment: I agree with your comment about index usage with '%' at the end of the pattern. But I don't think the query is planned at statement prepare time, so I don't agree with the latter part of your answer.

Comment: left-anchored and constant.  See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/indexes-types.html

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that in the first case the query compiler/optimizer detects that the clause is a constant, and can build an optimal query plan.  In the second it has to compile a more generic query because the bound variable can be anything at run-time.

Comment: why do think I am querying for `LIKE '%'`? I am concatenating '%' to a supplied `$q` and searching for that. For example, in both cases, I am searching for `LIKE 'abcde%'`, just doing the queries differently.

Comment: I missed the concatenation, sorry. I have edited my answer. However, I still think the basic premise might be valid.  In one case the query compiler gets a constant, which it can use in building a query plan.  In the other, the compiler must build a query plan for the general case where the bound variable could be anything.  You should examine the query plans to see if this is the case.  I have never worked with PG (just Oracle & MySQL) so I don't know how to examine the query plans.

Comment: yea, one interesting answer on the DBI mailing list is that perhaps the Pg query planner doesn't have as much information in a query with a bind value than in a query with the parameter inline. I am hoping to hear from others as well, because, if that is true, then it is a big strike against binding values in DBI, at least in this case.

Comment: This is just db planning. The problem with bind values is that Pg doesn't know anything about the statistics, so it has to create a plan that is best in the worst case.  Pg will only use indexes if the index will be faster and as a rule of thumb if the clause will select more than something like 5% of the table then a scan will generally be faster.  In the bindvar case, the planner assumes you might pass in "%" for which a full-table scan will be faster than an index scan.  In the constant expression case, it can estimate that the clause only hits a small enough subset.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running both test cases from same file using same $dbh object?
I think reason of increasing speed in second case is that you using prepared statement which is already parsed(but maybe I wrong:)).

Comment: Statement preparation is actually very fast and is only an issue if you are doing it a very large number of times. In this case only one query is prepared for a multi-million row query, so the effect (even if it were a factor) would be negligible.

Answer (score -1):

Ahh, I see - I will drop out after this comment since I don't know Perl.  But I would trust that the editor is correct in highlighting the $q as a constant.  I'm guessing that you need to concatenate the value into the string, rather than just directly referencing the variable.  So, my guess is that if + is used for string concatenation in perl, then use something like:

my $sql = qq{
    SELECT a, b, c
    FROM t 
    WHERE Lower( a ) LIKE '
} + $q + qq{'};

(Note: unless the language is tightly integrated with the database, such as Oracle/PLSQL, you usually have to create a completely valid SQL string before submitting to the database, instead of expecting the compiler to 'interpolate'/'Substitute' the value of the variable.)

I would again suggest that you get the COUNT() of the statements, to make sure  that you are comparing apple to apples.

Comment: Perl's concatenation operator is `.`, and `qq{ SELECT a, b, c FROM t WHERE Lower( a ) LIKE '$q'}` and `qq{ SELECT a, b, c FROM t WHERE Lower( a ) LIKE '} . $q . qq{'};` are identical.

Comment: If you don't know Perl, you should listen to those that do (mu, TLP).

Comment: @klofton: Sorry if I sound miserable, but as your answer is something of a red herring, I would suggest considering deleting it entirely.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know Postgres at all, but I think in Line 7 (WHERE Lower( a ) LIKE '$q'
), $q is actually a constant.  It looks like your editor thinks so too, since it is highlighted in red.  You probably still need to use the ? for the variable.

To test, do a COUNT(*), and make sure they match - I could be way offbase.

Comment: No, Perl's `qq{...}` acts like a double quoted string so `$q` will be interpolated.

Comment: It is not a constant. The statement is wrapped in `qq{}`, so variables are interpolated.

Comment: or, maybe try just removing the single-quotes around $q, and see if it compiles (this is how Oracle PL/SQL would process it, but not sure how scoping works in postgres).

Comment: it will compile fine, but it will be a completely different query. Without the single quotes it will be trying to do a LIKE against a column with the same name as the value of $q.

Comment: The value of `$q` is interpolated into the query because the string literal is a `qq{}` (interpolating) string literal. The single quotes either side of the `$q` inside the string do not stop `$q` being interpolated.

Comment: @klofton: Again, complete red herring. I would suggest considering deleting the answer entirely.